# Apache Calcite streaming SQL demo fails

Tags: sql, stream, apache-calcite

I wrote a streaming SQL query [as in the demo](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/stream.html):

```
SELECT STREAM TUMBLE_END(ROWTIME, INTERVAL '1' HOUR) AS rowtime,
  PRODUCT,
  COUNT(*) AS c,
  SUM(UNITS) AS units
FROM STREAMS.ORDERS
```

but got the error:

> Unable to implement EnumerableCalc(expr#0..3=[{inputs}],
> expr#4=[3600000:INTERVAL HOUR], expr#5=[+($t0, $t4)], rowtime=[$t5],
> PRODUCT=[$t1], c=[$t2], units=[$t3]): rowcount = 10.0, cumulative cost
> = {172.5 rows, 1050.0 cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 102   EnumerableAggregate(group=[{0, 1}], c=[COUNT()], units=[$SUM0($2)]):
> rowcount = 10.0, cumulative cost = {162.5 rows, 950.0 cpu, 0.0 io}, id
> = 98
> EnumerableCalc(expr#0..3=[{inputs}], expr#4=[3600000:INTERVAL HOUR], expr#5=[$TUMBLE($t0, $t4)], $f0=[$t5], PRODUCT=[$t2],
> UNITS=[$t3]): rowcount = 100.0, cumulative cost = {150.0 rows, 950.0
> cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 104
> EnumerableInterpreter: rowcount = 100.0, cumulative cost = {50.0 rows, 50.0 cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 94
> BindableTableScan(table=[[STREAMS, ORDERS, (STREAM)]]): rowcount = 100.0, cumulative cost = {100.0 rows, 101.0 cpu, 0.0 io},
> id = 85
>
> at org.apache.calcite.avatica.Helper.createException(Helper.java:56)
> at org.apache.calcite.avatica.Helper.createException(Helper.java:41)
> at
> org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaStatement.executeInternal(AvaticaStatement.java:164)
> at
> org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaStatement.executeQuery(AvaticaStatement.java:228)
> at
> com.calcite.example.example.StreamExample.testStream(StreamExample.java:57)
> at
> com.calcite.example.example.StreamExample.main(StreamExample.java:22)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to implement
> EnumerableCalc(expr#0..3=[{inputs}], expr#4=[3600000:INTERVAL HOUR],
> expr#5=[+($t0, $t4)], rowtime=[$t5], PRODUCT=[$t1], c=[$t2],
> units=[$t3]): rowcount = 10.0, cumulative cost = {172.5 rows, 1050.0
> cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 102   EnumerableAggregate(group=[{0, 1}],
> c=[COUNT()], units=[$SUM0($2)]): rowcount = 10.0, cumulative cost =
> {162.5 rows, 950.0 cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 98
> EnumerableCalc(expr#0..3=[{inputs}], expr#4=[3600000:INTERVAL HOUR], expr#5=[$TUMBLE($t0, $t4)], $f0=[$t5], PRODUCT=[$t2],
> UNITS=[$t3]): rowcount = 100.0, cumulative cost = {150.0 rows, 950.0
> cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 104

Can you help me?

```
  EnumerableInterpreter: rowcount = 100.0, cumulative cost = {50.0 rows, 50.0 cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 94
    BindableTableScan(table=[[STREAMS, ORDERS, (STREAM)]]): rowcount = 100.0, cumulative cost = {100.0 rows, 101.0 cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 85

at org.apache.calcite.adapter.enumerable.EnumerableRelImplementor.implementRoot(EnumerableRelImplementor.java:117)
at org.apache.calcite.adapter.enumerable.EnumerableInterpretable.toBindable(EnumerableInterpretable.java:112)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.CalcitePrepareImpl$CalcitePreparingStmt.implement(CalcitePrepareImpl.java:1159)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.Prepare.prepareSql(Prepare.java:324)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.Prepare.prepareSql(Prepare.java:220)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.CalcitePrepareImpl.prepare2_(CalcitePrepareImpl.java:665)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.CalcitePrepareImpl.prepare_(CalcitePrepareImpl.java:519)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.CalcitePrepareImpl.prepareSql(CalcitePrepareImpl.java:487)
at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteConnectionImpl.parseQuery(CalciteConnectionImpl.java:236)
at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteMetaImpl.prepareAndExecute(CalciteMetaImpl.java:621)
at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaConnection.prepareAndExecuteInternal(AvaticaConnection.java:677)
at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaStatement.executeInternal(AvaticaStatement.java:157)
... 3 more
Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot translate call $TUMBLE($t0, $t4)
    at org.apache.calcite.adapter.enumerable.RexToLixTranslator.visitCall(RexToLixTranslator.java:1172)
    at org.apache.calcite.adapter.enumerable.RexToLixTranslator.visitCall(RexToLixTranslator.java:98)
    at org.apache.calcite.rex.RexCall.accept(RexCall.java:189)
    at org.apache.calcite.adapter.enumerable.RexToLixTranslator.visitLocalRef(RexToLixTranslator.java:1059)
    at org.apache.calcite.adapter.enumerable.RexToLixTranslator.visitLocalRef(RexToLixTranslator.java:98)
    at org.apache.calcite.rex.RexLocalRef.accept(RexLocalRef.java:77)
    at org.apache.calcite.adapter.enumerable.RexToLixTranslator.translate(RexToLixTranslator.java:259)
    at org.apache.calcite.adapter.enumerable.RexToLixTranslator.translate(RexToLixTranslator.java:253)
    at org.apache.calcite.adapter.enumerable.RexToLixTranslator.translateList(RexToLixTranslator.java:899)
    at org.apache.calcite.adapter.enumerable.RexToLixTranslator.translateProjects(RexToLixTranslator.java:207)
    at org.apache.calcite.adapter.enumerable.EnumerableCalc.implement(EnumerableCalc.java:192)
    at org.apache.calcite.adapter.enumerable.EnumerableRelImplementor.visitChild(EnumerableRelImplementor.java:107)
    at org.apache.calcite.adapter.enumerable.EnumerableAggregate.implement(EnumerableAggregate.java:105)
    at org.apache.calcite.adapter.enumerable.EnumerableRelImplementor.visitChild(EnumerableRelImplementor.java:107)
    at org.apache.calcite.adapter.enumerable.EnumerableCalc.implement(EnumerableCalc.java:118)
    at org.apache.calcite.adapter.enumerable.EnumerableRelImplementor.implementRoot(EnumerableRelImplementor.java:114)
    ... 14 more
```

I want to expect result like demo result

Comment: can you share a data sample of stream.orders? are you sure you don't need the group by clause?

Comment: create table STREAMS.ORDERS(
id integer primary key,
rowtime timestamp,
product varchar,
unit integer
);